# Classify groups via theorem of finite abelian groups

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

by using the theorem of finite abelian groups, you can show that specific groups are isomorphisms to direct products of $\mathbb{Z}_n$. 
My question: If, for example, I only know that a group is ismorph to $\mathbb{Z}_4$ OR $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$, how do I determine which my group is isomorph to?

Comment: You can check if there is an element in your group with order 4.

Comment: How to go about something like this will depend heavily on how the group is given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on the precise information you have about your finite abelian group $G$, but if you know the order $|G|$ (as you do in your example), then one approach is as follows:

Find an element $g\in G$ of maximal order (you might do this by finding a generating set, again it depends on the precise information you have).

If $G\cong \mathbb{Z}_{d_1}\times\cdots\mathbb{Z}_{d_r}$ with $d_i|d_{i+1}$ for each $i$ then $|g|=d_r$ so you know $d_r$. Repeat with $G/\langle g \rangle\cong\mathbb{Z}_{d_1}\times\cdots\mathbb{Z}_{d_{r-1}}$ to find $d_{r-1}$ and so on (if you found a generating set for $G$ then the same set works for $G/\langle g \rangle$, so after the first $g$, finding an element of maximal order should be easy).

N.B. An alternative involves constructing and reducing a matrix using only certain operations to obtain the $d_i$ on the diagonal, which is significantly easier to do, but harder to explain. I suspect this is covered in most courses that prove the classification of finite abelian groups.